# How do I center an image in blogger slider?

Tags: html, css, slider, blogs

I'm a noob with this stuff so please try to dumb it down. I'm working on this blog slider: https://fluoresblog.blogspot.ca/

The images in the slider are cropped and not center. I'd like to keep the size of the slide but have the image centered. How would I do this? Thanks!

```
.flexslider ul.slides li .feature_text h2 a {
          color: #fff;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      display: block;
      font-family: Raleway;
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1.25;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.flexslider ul.slides li .feature_text p {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:1px 8px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.flexslider ul.slides li .feature_text span.feature_button {
    display:block;
}

.flexslider ul.slides li .feature_text span.feature_button a {
    border:3px solid #FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:11px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:700;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-family:Sans-serif;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
}

.flexslider ul.slides li .feature_text span.feature_button a:hover {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    border:3px solid #FFF;
}

.flexslider ul.slides li .feature_text span.feature_button a i.fa {
    margin-left:1px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

/*** flexslider gallery **/

```
.flexslider.gallery {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.flexslider .slides a.thumb {
display:block;
height:540px;
overflow:hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your slider images are put as background images try to set background-position css property as "center".

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: first of all you have to show me what part of HTML markup is responsible for showing the slider image

Comment: maybe the last section under flexislider gallery. Where is says slides a.thumb. When I fiddled with the height it changed the image/slider height.

Comment: try this

`.flexslider .slides a.thumb {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}`